# Why do my particles in particle system fall down instead of evaporating to create smoke?

Tags: particles, smoke-simulation

Why do my particles in the particle system fall down instead of evaporating to create smoke? I must have done something dramatically wrong, for I have tried this smoke effect from particles in 2 separate files, and in both the particles just fall down. No smoke ever! Please help:)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

1. Make sure you have your particle system and your smoke flow on the same flow object.
2. Make sure your flow object Flow Source is set to particle system and not mesh.

Make sure you do not add this to your domain object both the particle system and the smoke flow should be assigned to the same object. Also make sure that object fits inside your domain object.